# error RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, json, recyclerview

Estoy haciendo una app en java, y de cuando abro el activity que muestra un RecyclerView cargado desde un JSON me arroja un error y se cierra la app. Lo raro es que no siempre tira el error, me canse de revisarlo pero no encuentro en que estoy fallando.

JSON recibido:

```
{"pedido":{"1":{"id_pedido":"28","creado":"19-9 a las 2:08 am","tipo":"Envios particulares","estado":"En proceso (cadete asignado)"}}}
```

Codigo Java:

```
JSONObject row = response.getJSONObject("pedido");
                recycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.Listadope);
                recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
                lManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
                recycler.setLayoutManager(lManager);
                for(int x = 1; x < (row.length() + 1); x++)
                {
                    String value = Integer.toString(x);
                    JSONObject pedido = row.getJSONObject(value);
                    String id_pedido = pedido.getString("id_pedido");
                    String tipo = pedido.getString("tipo");
                    String estado = pedido.getString("estado");
                    String fecha = pedido.getString("creado");
                    items.add(new Pedido(id_pedido,tipo,estado,fecha));

                }
                adapter = new PedidoAdapter(items);
                recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Error que me muestra el log:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.xxx, PID: 30429
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/gchu/xxx/PedidoAdapter;
    at com.gchu.xxx.MisPedidosView$1.onResponse(MisPedidosView.java:103)
    at com.gchu.xxx.MisPedidosView$1.onResponse(MisPedidosView.java:78)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:90)
    at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.gchu.xxx.PedidoAdapter" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.gchu.xxx-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
    at com.gchu.aktiva.MisPedidosView$1.onResponse(MisPedidosView.java:103) 
    at com.gchu.aktiva.MisPedidosView$1.onResponse(MisPedidosView.java:78) 
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:90) 
    at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gchu.xxx.PedidoAdapter
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 13 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Ya no se me ocurre mas nada, soy nuevo en esto de java pero me resulta muy raro que hay veces que carga perfecto y muestra bien los resultados y hay veces que no.

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a el error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the
> boot class loader; no stack available

este problema debe suceder porque tienes habilitada la opciòn "Instant Run", te sugiero ir desde el menù de Android Studio y deshabilitar esta opciòn:

`File` > `Settings` > `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Instant Run`

Te sugiero actualizar Android Studio a la versiòn 4.0 o posterior.

Comment: Revise, pero no encuentro la opción que me decís.

Comment: Que version de Android Studio usas?

Comment: Uso la version 4.0.1